# Converting Factor to Date without creating NA's

Tags: r, class, date, cut, na

I'm running into problems converting factor to date; it is making NA values which I don't want.

Data for my problem can be found here: (https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/repdata%2Fdata%2Factivity.zip)

```
x <- read.csv("activity.csv")
head(x)

steps       date interval
1    NA 2012-10-01        0
2    NA 2012-10-01        5
3    NA 2012-10-01       10
4    NA 2012-10-01       15
5    NA 2012-10-01       20
6    NA 2012-10-01       25
```

Goal: I'm trying to find the mean total number of steps taken per day.  So first, I need to **bin values so that each data point corresponds to the sum for a given day**

```
x$Day <- as.Date(cut(x$date, breaks = "day"))

Error in cut.default(x$date, breaks = "day") : 'x' must be numeric
```

Just confirm this with *class* function

```
class(x[,2])
```

"factor"

This is weird because from the head(x) above it looked like it was Date. Anyways so in order to bin values so that each data point corresponds to the sum for a given day using the *cut* function I need to change the date's to "Date" class

```
x[,2] <- as.Date(x[,2], format="%Y/%m/%d")
class(x[,2])
```

[1] "Date"

OK, so in theory I should be able to bin values now

```
x$Day <- as.Date(cut(x$date, breaks = "day"))
```

Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' cannot be NA, NaN or infinite
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min.default(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,  :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max.default(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,  :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

```
head(is.na(x))

steps date interval
[1,]  TRUE TRUE    FALSE
[2,]  TRUE TRUE    FALSE
[3,]  TRUE TRUE    FALSE
[4,]  TRUE TRUE    FALSE
[5,]  TRUE TRUE    FALSE
[6,]  TRUE TRUE    FALSE
```

If I compare this to what I saw prior to the `x[,2] <- as.Date(x[,2], format="%Y/%m/%d")`

```
head(is.na(x))

steps  date interval
[1,]  TRUE FALSE    FALSE
[2,]  TRUE FALSE    FALSE
[3,]  TRUE FALSE    FALSE
[4,]  TRUE FALSE    FALSE
[5,]  TRUE FALSE    FALSE
[6,]  TRUE FALSE    FALSE
```

Not sure what's going on here? I know this should work because I got this idea from the following tutorial (http://blog.mollietaylor.com/2013/08/plot-weekly-or-monthly-totals-in-r.html?m=1)

```
sessionInfo()

R version 3.0.3 (2014-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Canada.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_Canada.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_Canada.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=English_Canada.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils    
[5] datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] scales_0.2.4  ggplot2_1.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] colorspace_1.2-4 digest_0.6.4    
[3] grid_3.0.3       gtable_0.1.2    
[5] MASS_7.3-29      munsell_0.4.2   
[7] plyr_1.8.1       proto_0.3-10    
[9] Rcpp_0.11.1      reshape2_1.4    
[11] stringr_0.6.2    tools_3.0.3
```

Comment: You should just set the right format separator "-" not "\" to get : `as.Date(x[,2], format="%Y-%m-%d")`

Comment: This all seems very confused to me. If what you have is dates, not datetimes, and you need to aggregate by day, why do you need to use `cut` at all? The data are already at the granularity you want. Then you have the format issue that agstudy mentioned, and the fact that `cut` always returns a factor of intervals, so it would never make sense to coerce the results of it back to date.

Answer (score 1):

Just to illustrate, these all result in the same output (except for the class of the date column of course):

```
x <- read.csv("~/Downloads/activity.csv")
# Date is a factor
r1 <- aggregate(steps~date,data = x,FUN = mean)

x1 <- read.csv("~/Downloads/activity.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# Date is a character
r2 <- aggregate(steps~date,data = x1,FUN = mean)

x2 <- x
x2$date <- as.Date(as.character(x$date))
# Date is a date
r3 <- aggregate(steps~date,data = x2,FUN = mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_data <-
  read.csv(your_file, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Convert 'my_data$date' to Date format
my_data$date <- 
  as.Date(my_data$date)
```

This should work...